# Is it possible to connect via ssh between 2 virtual machines on 2 different computers?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox

I would like to know if it's possible to connect via SSH between 2 VM on 2 different computers?

I created a private key :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I want to send this key to the other VM, but I don't know how I should do it. Which IP address should I use? Do I need to do some modifications in the network settings?

I don't know if it's useful information, but both of them are NAT.

Comment: Do it as if they were both non-VMs. Just make sure they both have available network interfaces. Aside from that, nothing else needs to be done.